# Not getting any data after form submission in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

**After submitting my form I am not getting the submitted data on console and also the page is not routing**

I am not getting the reason behind this. Searching for 2 days but still not got a suitable answer. Can anyone tell me the solution?

```
import axios from "axios";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
// import { createBrowserHistory as history } from "history";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import DoneStatus from "./DoneStatus";

class Body extends React.Component {
  titleDescMap = new Map();
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeTitle = this.handleChangeTitle.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeDescription = this.handleChangeDescription.bind(this);
    this.handleCheckBoxChange = this.handleCheckBoxChange.bind(this);
  }

  state = {
    countTodo: 1,
    valueTitle: "",
    valueDescription: "",
    checkStatus: false,
    routing: false,
  };

  statesStatus() {
    return {
      checkStatus: this.state.checkStatus,
    };
  }

  handleChangeTitle(event) {
    this.setState({
      valueTitle: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  handleChangeDescription(event) {
    this.setState({
      valueDescription: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  handleCheckBoxChange(event) {
    this.setState((prev) => ({ checkStatus: !prev.checkStatus }));
    console.log(this.state.checkStatus);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    // Debugging my states
    console.log("Id: " + this.state.id);
    console.log("Title: " + this.state.valueTitle);
    console.log("Description: " + this.state.valueDescription);
    console.log("Check Status: " + this.state.checkStatus);
    event.preventDefault();

    var previousTitle = this.titleDescMap.has(this.state.valueTitle);

    // Sending data to database

    // Checking if any title and desc is previously stored
    if (previousTitle) {
      alert("Please Enter Another Title (which you have never used)");
    } else {
      // Setting the values in title and description into Map
      this.titleDescMap.set(this.state.valueTitle, this.state.valueDescription);
      console.log(this.titleDescMap);

      // Updating id as counter increases 1
      this.setState((previousState) => ({
        countTodo: previousState.countTodo + 1,
      }));

      if (this.state.checkStatus) {
        const backendData = {
          countTodo: this.state.countTodo,
          title: this.state.valueTitle,
          description: this.state.valueDescription,
        };

        axios
          .post("https://todo-list-site.herokuapp.com/todo-data", backendData)
          .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.props.history.push("/submit");
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error("Error");
          });

        console.log(backendData);
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.checkStatus);
    return (
      <div className="body-container">
        <p className="body-direction">Fill To Save Your Todo</p>
        <form method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Title here"
              value={this.state.valueTitle}
              onChange={this.handleChangeTitle}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Description</label>
            <br />
            <textarea
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Description here"
              rows="4"
              cols="40"
              value={this.state.valueDescription}
              onChange={this.handleChangeDescription}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-check">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              className="form-check-input"
              onChange={this.handleCheckBoxChange}
            />
            <label className="form-check-label body-input-label">
              Save Permanently
            </label>
          </div>
          <button
            type="submit"
            // onClick={() => history().push("/submit")}
            className="btn btn-primary"
          >
            + Add
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Body);
```

**I have updated my code as per the given solution on this question. But still not getting the proper output**

I want to send all the data in the form into my backend and render it on another page.
Data is submitting but I am not getting it on the console. Also routing is the major issue here.

**I have added the file which includes all the routes**

```
import Header from "./Header";
import Body from "./Body";
import DoneStatus from "./DoneStatus";
import Saved from "./Saved";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
// import Footer from "./Footer";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const body = new Body();
    const checkStatus = body.statesStatus();
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Router>
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/"
              render={() => {
                return (
                  <div className="app-container">
                    <Body />
                  </div>
                );
              }}
            ></Route>
          </Switch>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/saved"
              render={() => {
                return <Saved />;
              }}
            ></Route>
          </Switch>
          {/* <Footer /> */}
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/submit"
              render={() => {
                return <DoneStatus checkedStatus={checkStatus.checkStatus} />;
              }}
            ></Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Possible typo: `history().push("/submit");` should be `history.push("/submit");`. Can you explain what and were you are expecting something in the console, is it the `console.log(backendData);` log?

Comment: @DrewReese calling `history.push()` is telling that no method is available for history. But `history()` is showing method push(). That's why I have used that. Also `history.push('/submit')` isn't routing my page

Comment: Oh, you are creating a new history object. Don't do that. Use the `this.props.history` object that the `withRouter` HOC is (presumably) providing. Your router doesn't know about *this* new `history` object you are creating so navigation will be wonky or not work at all.

Comment: @DrewReese `this.props.history` means I will have to pass argument `history` in my Body Component wherever I will use Body? Ok, So I have done this and it is showing `Cannot read property 'wrappedComponentRef' of undefined` and my changed code is `this.props.history.push("/submit");` and `export default withRouter(Body);
` ..... `import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
`

Comment: No, the `withRouter` HOC injects [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) into the component it decorates, you won't need to pass any additional props. Where you *not* using the `withRouter` HOC previously?

Comment: Okay, so why I am getting `Cannot read property 'wrappedComponentRef' of undefined` this error? Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Dunno, what's throwing that error? Is there a stacktrace that tells you what and where that you can include in your question? Can you show how you are using `withRouter` and exporting that component and where it's used and rendered?

Comment: @DrewReese I have editted my code. You can see.

Comment: Ok Done...Thank You for helping me :) Problem is sorted now

Comment: Sorry, I'd signed off for the night already, but happy help. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not waiting for your `POST` to finish, and as @Drew Reese points, you are calling the `history` wrong

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  // Debugging my states
  console.log("Id: " + this.state.id);
  console.log("Title: " + this.state.valueTitle);
  console.log("Description: " + this.state.valueDescription);
  console.log("Check Status: " + this.state.checkStatus);
  event.preventDefault();

  var previousTitle = this.titleDescMap.has(this.state.valueTitle);

  // Sending data to database

  // Checking if any title and desc is previously stored
  if (previousTitle) {
    alert("Please Enter Another Title (which you have never used)");
  } else {
    // Setting the values in title and description into Map
    this.titleDescMap.set(this.state.valueTitle, this.state.valueDescription);
    console.log(this.titleDescMap);

    // Updating id as counter increases 1
    this.setState((previousState) => ({
      countTodo: previousState.countTodo + 1,
    }));

    if (this.state.checkStatus) {
      const backendData = {
        countTodo: this.state.countTodo,
        title: this.state.valueTitle,
        description: this.state.valueDescription,
      };

      axios.post(
        "https://todo-list-site.herokuapp.com/todo-data",
        backendData
      ).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        history.push("/submit");
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

    }
  }
}
```

Also, you are not waiting for the `countTodo` state to be setted after getting it to send it to the backend, that might get you unexpected behaviours some times

Comment: I am not able to identify that why I am not getting any data on my console? Also, still not able to route my page using `history.push("/submit")`

Comment: What are you expecting to see in your console? you should be seeing the exact object your saving `console.log(backendData);`. And you probably are seeing the console before is been stored, because your ar not waiting for the POST to finish to console the data.

Comment: I have used `console.log()` in many places such as in the render method. At least that data should be printed because it is not dependent on the post method. I want to see the status of my `checkStatus` state when I click on checkbox. But not getting any of the output on console. Can you please explain me if I am doing wrong. I am new to ReactJS.

Comment: That is strange, you should be seeing the consoles. Is there any error on your console? It looks like your having a previous error and your Body component actions are not being executed

Comment: I have updated my code. Sorry, mistakenly I updated yours, you can reject

Comment: If you don't see the `console.log(this.state.checkStatus);` on the render, you must probably have an error somewhere previous to this component render.

Comment: Ok, so the console problem is solved. Thank you :) Can you plz solve the major problem which is the routing issue?

Comment: The routing should be something like  @Drew Reese is commenting. If you put on your question the component where you manage your routes we might be able you help you see the problem there.

Comment: Why do you have multiple `Switch`s? put all your routes inside a single switch (https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch). Also no need to use the render prop in your case, just put it like: `<Route exact path="/saved"><Saved /></Route>`

Comment: Thank You for helping me... Problem is sorted now :)

Comment: No prob. Don't forget to highlight wich comments / responses were useful so other users can use them to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing handling promise, please find below solution:

```
axios.get(`https://todo-list-site.herokuapp.com/todo-data`)
  .then(backendData => {
    console.log(backendData);
  })
```